# SVN EXPORT to Remove From Source Control

Tags: svn, export

I am trying to remove a folder from source control.  I want to leave the local folder alone and just have it no longer be associated with a repository.

According to other answered questions, SVN EXPORT is the way to remove a folder from source control.  And so I enter SVN EXPORT PATH1 PATH2 and omit PATH2:

prompt>svn export /var/www
Export complete.

prompt>

However when I run
prompt>svn info /var/www

It gives me all the same info
Path: /var/www
URL: https://someurl/somefolder
Repository Root: https://...... etc.

I am looking it for it to say:
"var/www is not a working folder" or 
"var/www is not under source control"

And so I have issued the Export command but it still appears to be under source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delete the subversion metadata. This will be a hidden folder called `.svn` in your folder and in each subfolder - delete these and they'll no longer be a working copy.

Just svn export won't work because it will overwrite the existing files in place but not delete the `.svn` folders which still exist on disk. You could also simply delete the folder then re-export in place.

To be clear: this solution removes the association with the repository for that folder in your working copy but will not remove the files from the repository itself (which is how I read what you're asking). If you want to actually delete the files from the repository then you want `svn rm`, Eugene's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want `svn del --keep-local`.

Comment: When I enter<br/>svn del --keep-local<br/> it returns<br />svn: Not enough arguments provided<br /><br />When I enter svn del /var/www --keep-local<br />it returns<br/>svn: '/var' is not a working copy

Comment: @Eric this is the way I would go about it too. You should have to do svn del [path] --keep-local, then commit the change. If you deleted your .svn, as suggested above, you'll have lost the metadata SVN needs to accomplish this.